# Installing npm fails on Mac OSX

Tags: node.js, tar, npm

I receive an error when installing NPM as follows:

> ```
> gzip: stdin: decompression OK, trailing garbage ignored
> /usr/local/bin/tar: Child returned status 2
> /usr/local/bi/tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
> It failed
> ```

My set up:

- Mac OS X 10.6.3
- GNU tar v1.26
- Node v0.4.12

Any help greatly appreciated.

Full output:

> ```
> curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
> Password:
>   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
> 100  7147  100  7147    0     0  40849      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 86108
> tar=/usr/local/bin/tar
> version:
> tar (GNU tar) 1.26
> Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <"http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html">.
> This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
> There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
>
> Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
> Installing without make. This may fail.
> fetching: "http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.0.96.tgz"
>
> gzip: stdin: decompression OK, trailing garbage ignored
> /usr/local/bin/tar: Child returned status 2
> /usr/local/bin/tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
> It failed
> ```

Answer (score 0):

"Installing without make"

Install make on your system

you can get make by installing the developer tools that came with your mac, or through a package manager.

I like Homebrew:
[Link](https://brew.sh/)